# Change image styling by hovering over ::after element

Tags: html, css, image, opacity

I have a primary image with a secondoary image of an arrow on top, where the arrow is inserted by using a pseudo after-element.

Now I would like to change the opacity of the primary image when hovering over it. This works fine, until someone hovers the arrow image on top - then it doesn't. How can I place a hover style on the secondary arrow image, which changes opacity of the primary image?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that hovering over the arrow doesn't apply the hover style to the image?

Comment: what did you tried so far..?

Comment: Yes. When hovering over the primary image, the opacity changes as intended. When hovering over the arrow op top of the primary image, the primary image doesnt change..

Comment: I don't think you are able to change the values of other elements than the one you're hovering over. Not sure, though.

Comment: I have done the code like this:
http://oi64.tinypic.com/drbmuq.jpg

How would I make the image change opacity when hovering the ::after element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying this css to your pseudo after-element:

```
pointer-events:none
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a wrapper, and to make hover for it, like this:

```
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='img'></div>
</div>
```

And, add style like this:

```
.wrap:hover + .img {
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I am working on a site where everything is setup in content views (I know - but can't do anything about it..) I cant add any wrappers. Can I use the same method on the existing layout?
http://oi63.tinypic.com/29zaddt.jpg